# Removing a <video> tag from a set of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

`var v = $("<video>").attr('poster', '/images/user.png').attr('height', '64').attr('width', '64').appendTo("#remoteVideos");`

Basically this is run everytime a new user connects, therefore a new video element is created.

When a user disconnects, I need to remove 1 (ONE)  element. It actually doesn't matter which.

How would I go about doing this?

I came across this but not sure how to use it or if it would work.

`var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
x.remove(x.selectedIndex);`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many video tags you have in the document? just one?

Comment: What does disconnect mean in this context?

Comment: x.parentNode.removeChild(x)

Comment: @TilwinJoy from 1 to 15. Usually around 5.

Comment: @Anthony It's not really relevant to the question I guess but basically when a user disconnects from a WebSocket. For all intents and purposes, I just need it to run within a function :)

Comment: @Kriiv - it's kind of relevant to the question since you mention it in your question. "disconnect" could mean when the video stops playing (so maybe that video needs to be the target to be removed) or it could mean "leaves the page" in which case your question doesn't make total sense, or it could mean "disconnects from some other external page", etc.  Not to mention your question basically asks "how do I randomly remove any video element from a page when some event that I'm saying isn't relevant occurs" which is pretty confusing. Why would you want to remove just any random video element?

Comment: @Anthony Sorry, didn't mean to sound rude. Thanks for the explanation how it could differ depending on what disconnect means. I'm very new to JS, my apologies. The below answers solved my issue. I am using XSockets and a function is called when a user closes the page (im guessing that counts as a socket disconnection). I needed some code to put inside that function that would remove a `video` element. Hope that clears it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using JQuery you can use `remove`.

And because you don't want to remove all your objects with a specific selector, you can use `eq`, `first`, `last` methods to target a specific video element.

Following code will remove the last `video` tag of your page.

```
$('video').last().remove();
```

Or for removing the first one

```
$('video').first().remove();
```

Or for removing a specific one

```
$('video').eq(5).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't matter which one, then try this simple method `.remove()`.

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

```
$('video').remove();
```

This would remove **all** video elements. So, try making sure a simple parameter of class or id is passed, or a simple parameter number is passed as:

```
$('video[0]').remove();
```

Class or ID

```
$('.video, #video').remove();
```

You can learn more at the link I provided!

Comment: Also, inline with the 2nd code block, $('video')[0].remove();  and  $('video').get(0).remove();